.desktop file does not work
I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I have the a file, arduino_ide.desktop, in /usr/share/applications/, but when I click on Activities and search for arduino_ide nothing shows up.
Here is the file:
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Arduino IDE
Comment=Arduino IDE for fun
GenericName=Embedded electronics IDE
Keywords=Programming;Development
Exec=/opt/arduino-ide_2.3.4/arduino-ide
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=/opt/arduino-ide_2.3.4/arduino-ide.png
Categories=Development;
MimeType=text/x-arduino;
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=Arduino IDE
X-AppImage-Version=2.3.4

I can start the arduino-ide by typing /opt/arduino-ide_2.3.4/arduino-ide, and clicking on the icon works. I used sudo desktop-file-install to install the arduino_ide.desktop file, and there were no errors reported.

That worked. Thanks. I don't understand why desktop_file_install automatically puts desktop files in /usr/share/applications. Also, if all users on the system needed access to a desktop file, it would go in /usr/share/applications, but placing a desktop file there does not seem to work.

Try this:
Open a terminal.
Run in it:
cp /usr/share/applications/arduino_ide.desktop  ~/.local/share/applications/
